# How to bind XML to a DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I have an app that receives XML from a server. I want to bind the data to a data grid and it would be grate if the grid auto generated the columns. So far I have tried to this much in my code.

XAML page:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</data:DataGrid>
```

Code behind for the page:

```
void Status_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XElement recordSet = XElement.Load(e.Result);
    CamerasStatusTabDataGrid.ItemsSource = recordSet.Elements("Status");
}
```

XML from the server:

```
<StatusReport>
    <Status Description="Spilled Coffe on Server" Date="2/5/2009" />
    <Status Description="Mice in Copier" Date="4/3/2008" />
    <Status Description="Helped User Find Any Key" Date="6/2/2008" />
</StatusReport>
```

What I am looking to do is to have the status be a row in the grid with "Description" and "Date" being columns.

Comment: I have updated my original post. It worked on my machine. :-)

Comment: Does the code works for you. Its not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is using Linq to Xml, the following is a full example:

Page.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    Width="400" Height="300"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <data:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = GetStatusReport();
        }

        public List<Status> GetStatusReport()
        {
            List<Status> statusReport = new List<Status>();

            // Get your Xml using XElement.Load(e.Result);
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"Data/StatusReport.xml");

            statusReport = (from el in doc.Elements()
                            select GetStatus(el)).ToList();

            return statusReport;
        }

        private Status GetStatus(XElement el)
        {
            Status s = new Status();
            s.Description = el.Attribute("Description").Value;
            s.Date = DateTime.Parse(el.Attribute("Date").Value);
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you add a reference to the System.Xml.Linq assembly.  This produces the output you were looking for with a Status for every row in the grid with "Description" and "Date" as columns.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aa3f9978fc.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aa3f9978fc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the following [link](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-(C).aspx).

It contains running code (on my environment) that creates a class with properties
at runtime. 
The class is used to populate a generic IList<object> that can serve
as source for the datagrid.

I didn't feel confortable posting the code here because 99.99999% of it is not
mine.

The links takes you to the original post where you will find the Silverlight working
code as a comment posted by me.

I posted another approach a while ago using a value converter: [Dynamically Bind XML to DataGrid in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230742/dynamically-bind-xml-to-datagrid-in-silverlight/3232505#3232505)

Comment: This is a good tutorial. However, I'm looking for a way to bind the data dynamically since i may not know the names of all the columns.